# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decode, encode

I have list like so:

```
l=[u'\u0634\u0628\u06a9\u0647 \u0645\u062d\u0628\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0644 \u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645', u'\u0622\u062e\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u0647\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u0647\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u062a \u0628\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0646\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u0646\u0642\u06cc \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645', u'\u0648\u0631\u0648\u062f', u'\u0622\u062e\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0622\u0646\u0644\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0647\u0627', u'\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644', u'\u06af\u0631\u0648\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644', u'\u0645\u062d\u0628\u0648\u0628\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0628\u0631\u0686\u0633\u0628 \u0647\u0627', u'\u0628\u0647 \u067e\u0627\u062a\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0646\u062a\u06cc \u0645\u062d\u0628\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0644 \u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u062e\u0648\u0634 \u0622\u0645\u062f\u06cc\u062f', u'\u06cc\u0627 \u062d\u0633\u06cc\u0646(\u0639)...\n\n\u0645\u06cc \u0628\u0631\u0645 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0631\u0648\u0632 \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u0635\u0644\u06cc\u062a\u0645\n\u0622\u062e\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u0639\u0634\u0642\u062a \u0639\u0631\u0627\u0642\u06cc \u0645\u06cc \u0634\u0648\u0645..', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645\n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645\n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'\u062f\u062e\u062a\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u0648\u0645\u0646 \u0633\u0647 \u0648\u06cc\u0698\u06af\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0646\u062f:\n      \u0645\u062a\u06a9\u0628\u0631\u060c\u0628\u062e\u06cc\u0644 \u0648 \u062a\u0631\u0633\u0648 \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0646\u062f!\n\n \ufe8d\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0645\u0646\u06cc\u0646 \ufecb\ufee0\ufbfd (\u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645) \ufee3\ufbfd \ufed3\ufeae\ufee3\ufe8e\ufbfe\ufee8\ufeaa:\n\n\ufeaf\ufee7\ufe8e\ufee5 \ufeed \ufea9\ufea7\ufe98\ufeae\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufee3\ufeee\ufee3\ufee6 \ufe91\ufe8e\ufbfe\ufeaa \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee6 \ufeb3\ufeea \ufebb\ufed4\ufe96 \ufead\ufe8d \ufb90\ufeea \ufe91\ufeae\ufe8d\ufbfc \ufee3\ufeae\ufea9\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufe91\ufeaa \ufe8d\ufeb3\ufe96\u060c\ufea9\ufe8d\ufeb7\ufe98\ufeea \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\ufe8d\ufeed\ufedd \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufee3\ufe98\ufb91\ufe92\ufeae \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\ufea9\ufbfe\ufb95\ufeae \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb3\ufeee \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\ufeed \ufeb3\ufeee\ufee1 \ufeeb\ufee2 \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufe91\ufea8\ufbff\ufede \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\n\ufe8d\ufee3\ufe8e \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufee3\ufe98\ufb91\ufe92\ufeae \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa \ufbfe\ufecc\ufee8\ufbfd \ufea9\ufead \ufee3\ufed8\ufe8e\ufe91\ufede \ufee7\ufe8e\ufee3\ufea4\ufeae\ufee1 \ufe91\ufe8e \ufed7\ufe8e\ufec3\ufecc\ufbff\ufe96 \ufeed \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb7\ufeae\ufeed\ufbfe\ufbfd \ufebb\ufea4\ufe92\ufe96 \ufb90\ufee8\ufee8\ufeaa \ufeed \ufe8d\ufeaf \ufea3\ufeae\ufed1 \ufeaf\ufea9\ufee5 \ufe91\ufe8e \ufecb\ufeb8\ufeee\ufee9 \ufeed \ufe97\ufe92\ufeb4\ufee2 \ufb90\ufeea \ufea9\ufbfe\ufb95\ufeae\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufead\ufe8d \ufe97\ufea4\ufeae\ufbfe\ufb8f \ufee3\ufbff\ufb91\ufee8\ufeaa \ufe91\ufb59\ufeae\ufeeb\ufbff\ufeb0\ufee7\ufeaa.\n\n\ufee3\ufee8\ufec8\ufeee\ufead \ufe8d\ufeaf \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb1 \ufeeb\ufee2 \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb1 \ufe8d\ufeaf \ufe97\ufee8\ufeec\ufe8e \ufe91\ufeee\ufea9\ufee5 \ufeed \ufe97\ufee8\ufeec\ufe8e \ufee3\ufe8e\ufee7\ufeaa\ufee5 \ufe91\ufe8e \ufeb7\ufea8\ufebc\ufbfd \ufe8d\ufeb3\ufe96 \ufb90\ufeea \ufecb\ufee8\ufeee\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufee7\ufe8e\ufee3\ufea4\ufeae\ufee1 \ufea9\ufe8d\ufead\ufea9.\n\n\ufe8d\ufee3\ufe8e \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufe91\ufea8\ufbff\ufede \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufeaa \ufbfe\ufecc\ufee8\ufbfd \ufea9\ufead \ufea3\ufed4\ufec6 \ufee3\ufe8e\u0644 \ufea7\ufeee\ufea9 \ufeed \ufeb7\ufeee\ufeeb\ufeae\u060c\ufb90\ufee4\ufe8e\ufedd \ufea9\ufed7\ufe96 \ufeed \ufeed\ufeb3\ufeee\ufe8d\ufeb1 \ufead\ufe8d \ufe91\ufeea \ufea7\ufeae\ufe9d \ufea9\ufeeb\ufeaa \ufeed \ufe8d\ufee3\ufe8e\ufee7\ufe96 \ufea9\ufe8d\ufead \ufe8d\ufee3\ufeee\ufe8d\ufedd \ufeeb\ufee4\ufeb4\ufeae \ufea7\ufeee\ufea9 \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufeaa.\n\n\ufee7\ufeec\ufe9e \ufe8d\ufedf\ufe92\ufefc\u200c\ufecf\ufeea \ufed3\ufbff\ufebe \ufe8d\ufefb\u200c\ufeb3\ufefc\u200c\u0645 \ufea3\ufb91\ufee4\ufe96266\u060c\ufeb91191', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n\n\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647\u0645 \u0639\u062c\u0644 \u0644\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u06a9 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0631\u062c', u'', u'', u'.........', u'\u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0627\u0621\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0642\u0633\u0645\u062a \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0639\u0627\u0634\u0642\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0632 \u062c\u0645\u0644\u0647 \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u0628\u0634\u0647.', u'\u0645\u0645\u0646\u0648\u0646 \u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0627\u0621\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647', u'++++++++', u'\u0639\u06a9\u0633 \u0648 \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0633 \n\r\n\u062e\u0631\u0627\u0628\u0647 \u0686\u0631\u0627\u063a\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0627\u0645\u0634\u0628 ...', u'', u'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u06a9 \u06cc\u0627 \u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0627\u062f\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0639\u0627\u0638\u0645 #\u0627\u062d\u0645\u062f-\u0628\u0646-\u0645\u0648\u0633\u06cc-\u0627\u0644\u06a9\u0627\u0638\u0645', u'\u0627\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631 \u0631\u0633\u0627\u0646\u0647\u200c\u0647\u0627']
```

I want to make it to utf-8 and see my data. so I've tried:

```
a=u', '.join(x.decode('unicode-escape') for x in l)
```

But the following error occurs:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

There is no problem on my list2:

```
l2=['\u0648', '\u062f\u0633\u062a\u0648\u0631', '\u062a\u0648' ,'\u0631\u0627 \u0633\u0628\u06a9' ,'\u0634\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0645!\n\n\u0648']
print u', '.join(x.decode('unicode-escape') for x in l2)
و, دستور, تو, را سبک, شمارم!

و
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to decode it? `print ', '.join(l)` works fine.

Comment: Not super helpful, but going to point out: The headache that is dealing with non-ASCII text and the discrepancies between `str` and `unicode` types is one of the major selling points for switching to Python 3. Python 3 has only one text type, `str`, and it handles the entire Unicode range natively.

Comment: I just recommend you look through http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html to make unicode problems go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `encode` your `unicode` to `utf-8` or any other encoding. (In python2)

```
l = '\u0634\u0628\u06a9\u0647 \u0645\u062d\u0628\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0644 \u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'
>>> print l.encode('utf-8')
شبکه محبان اهل بیت علیهم السلام
```

In your case, use the code below:

```
a = ', '.join(x.encode('utf-8') for x in l)
```

Comment: `unicode.encode()` returns `str`, so you should actually omitt the `u` prefix from the string you call `.join()` upon.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just copied OP's question. update.

Comment: please, do not `encode()` using a hardcoded encoding (you may get a mojibake if the environment uses an incompatible encoding), print Unicode directly instead (so that the environment settings are used (locale, `PYTHONIOENCODING`, `win-unicode-console`)).

Answer (score 5):

You already have unicode objects, there is no need to encode or decode in order to print them

**Python3.5**

```
>>> a=', '.join(l)
>>> a
'شبکه محبان اهل بیت علیهم السلام, آخرین فعالیت ها در هادی نت برگرفته از نام امام نقی علیه السلام, ورود, آخاتوق اینترنتی محبان اهل بیت علیهم السلام خو'
```

**Python2.7.10**

```
>>> l=",".join(l)
>>> print l
شبکه محبان اهل بیت علیهم السلام,آخرین فعالیت ها در هادی نت برگرفته از نام امام نقی علیه السلام,ور
```

Comment: Why even use the generator expressions? `','.join(x for x in l)` is just a slow way to say `','.join(l)`.

Comment: `print(', '.join(L))` -- single source Python 2/3 compatible variant.

Answer (score 2):

your `l` is list of unicode string, so just use them like normal string

```
l=[u'\u0634\u0628\u06a9\u0647 \u0645\u062d\u0628\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0644 \u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645', u'\u0622\u062e\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u0647\u0627 \u062f\u0631 \u0647\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u062a \u0628\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0646\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u0646\u0642\u06cc \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645', u'\u0648\u0631\u0648\u062f', u'\u0622\u062e\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0622\u0646\u0644\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0647\u0627', u'\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644', u'\u06af\u0631\u0648\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644', u'\u0645\u062d\u0628\u0648\u0628\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0628\u0631\u0686\u0633\u0628 \u0647\u0627', u'\u0628\u0647 \u067e\u0627\u062a\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0646\u062a\u06cc \u0645\u062d\u0628\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0644 \u0628\u06cc\u062a \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u062e\u0648\u0634 \u0622\u0645\u062f\u06cc\u062f', u'\u06cc\u0627 \u062d\u0633\u06cc\u0646(\u0639)...\n\n\u0645\u06cc \u0628\u0631\u0645 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0631\u0648\u0632 \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u0635\u0644\u06cc\u062a\u0645\n\u0622\u062e\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u0639\u0634\u0642\u062a \u0639\u0631\u0627\u0642\u06cc \u0645\u06cc \u0634\u0648\u0645..', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645\n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645\n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'\u062f\u062e\u062a\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u0648\u0645\u0646 \u0633\u0647 \u0648\u06cc\u0698\u06af\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0646\u062f:\n      \u0645\u062a\u06a9\u0628\u0631\u060c\u0628\u062e\u06cc\u0644 \u0648 \u062a\u0631\u0633\u0648 \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0646\u062f!\n\n \ufe8d\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0645\u0646\u06cc\u0646 \ufecb\ufee0\ufbfd (\u0639\u0644\u06cc\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645) \ufee3\ufbfd \ufed3\ufeae\ufee3\ufe8e\ufbfe\ufee8\ufeaa:\n\n\ufeaf\ufee7\ufe8e\ufee5 \ufeed \ufea9\ufea7\ufe98\ufeae\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufee3\ufeee\ufee3\ufee6 \ufe91\ufe8e\ufbfe\ufeaa \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee6 \ufeb3\ufeea \ufebb\ufed4\ufe96 \ufead\ufe8d \ufb90\ufeea \ufe91\ufeae\ufe8d\ufbfc \ufee3\ufeae\ufea9\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufe91\ufeaa \ufe8d\ufeb3\ufe96\u060c\ufea9\ufe8d\ufeb7\ufe98\ufeea \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\ufe8d\ufeed\ufedd \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufee3\ufe98\ufb91\ufe92\ufeae \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\ufea9\ufbfe\ufb95\ufeae \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb3\ufeee \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\ufeed \ufeb3\ufeee\ufee1 \ufeeb\ufee2 \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufe91\ufea8\ufbff\ufede \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa.\n\n\n\ufe8d\ufee3\ufe8e \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufee3\ufe98\ufb91\ufe92\ufeae \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufee8\ufeaa \ufbfe\ufecc\ufee8\ufbfd \ufea9\ufead \ufee3\ufed8\ufe8e\ufe91\ufede \ufee7\ufe8e\ufee3\ufea4\ufeae\ufee1 \ufe91\ufe8e \ufed7\ufe8e\ufec3\ufecc\ufbff\ufe96 \ufeed \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb7\ufeae\ufeed\ufbfe\ufbfd \ufebb\ufea4\ufe92\ufe96 \ufb90\ufee8\ufee8\ufeaa \ufeed \ufe8d\ufeaf \ufea3\ufeae\ufed1 \ufeaf\ufea9\ufee5 \ufe91\ufe8e \ufecb\ufeb8\ufeee\ufee9 \ufeed \ufe97\ufe92\ufeb4\ufee2 \ufb90\ufeea \ufea9\ufbfe\ufb95\ufeae\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufead\ufe8d \ufe97\ufea4\ufeae\ufbfe\ufb8f \ufee3\ufbff\ufb91\ufee8\ufeaa \ufe91\ufb59\ufeae\ufeeb\ufbff\ufeb0\ufee7\ufeaa.\n\n\ufee3\ufee8\ufec8\ufeee\ufead \ufe8d\ufeaf \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb1 \ufeeb\ufee2 \ufe97\ufeae\ufeb1 \ufe8d\ufeaf \ufe97\ufee8\ufeec\ufe8e \ufe91\ufeee\ufea9\ufee5 \ufeed \ufe97\ufee8\ufeec\ufe8e \ufee3\ufe8e\ufee7\ufeaa\ufee5 \ufe91\ufe8e \ufeb7\ufea8\ufebc\ufbfd \ufe8d\ufeb3\ufe96 \ufb90\ufeea \ufecb\ufee8\ufeee\ufe8d\ufee5 \ufee7\ufe8e\ufee3\ufea4\ufeae\ufee1 \ufea9\ufe8d\ufead\ufea9.\n\n\ufe8d\ufee3\ufe8e \ufe8d\ufbfe\ufee8\ufb91\ufeea \ufe91\ufea8\ufbff\ufede \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufeaa \ufbfe\ufecc\ufee8\ufbfd \ufea9\ufead \ufea3\ufed4\ufec6 \ufee3\ufe8e\u0644 \ufea7\ufeee\ufea9 \ufeed \ufeb7\ufeee\ufeeb\ufeae\u060c\ufb90\ufee4\ufe8e\ufedd \ufea9\ufed7\ufe96 \ufeed \ufeed\ufeb3\ufeee\ufe8d\ufeb1 \ufead\ufe8d \ufe91\ufeea \ufea7\ufeae\ufe9d \ufea9\ufeeb\ufeaa \ufeed \ufe8d\ufee3\ufe8e\ufee7\ufe96 \ufea9\ufe8d\ufead \ufe8d\ufee3\ufeee\ufe8d\ufedd \ufeeb\ufee4\ufeb4\ufeae \ufea7\ufeee\ufea9 \ufe91\ufe8e\ufeb7\ufeaa.\n\n\ufee7\ufeec\ufe9e \ufe8d\ufedf\ufe92\ufefc\u200c\ufecf\ufeea \ufed3\ufbff\ufebe \ufe8d\ufefb\u200c\ufeb3\ufefc\u200c\u0645 \ufea3\ufb91\ufee4\ufe96266\u060c\ufeb91191', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u0647\u0640\u064f\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e \u0635\u064e\u0640\u0644\u0651\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0640\u06cc #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0622\u0644\u0650 #\u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0640\u0640\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u062c\u0651\u0650\u0640\u0640\u0644\u0652 \u0641\u0640\u064e\u0640\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0640\u0647\u064f\u0645 \n\n\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647\u0645 \u0639\u062c\u0644 \u0644\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u06a9 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0631\u062c', u'', u'', u'.........', u'\u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0627\u0621\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0642\u0633\u0645\u062a \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0639\u0627\u0634\u0642\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0632 \u062c\u0645\u0644\u0647 \u0634\u0645\u0627 \u0628\u0634\u0647.', u'\u0645\u0645\u0646\u0648\u0646 \u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0627\u0621\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647', u'++++++++', u'\u0639\u06a9\u0633 \u0648 \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0633 \n\r\n\u062e\u0631\u0627\u0628\u0647 \u0686\u0631\u0627\u063a\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0627\u0645\u0634\u0628 ...', u'', u'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u06cc\u06a9 \u06cc\u0627 \u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0627\u062f\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0639\u0627\u0638\u0645 #\u0627\u062d\u0645\u062f-\u0628\u0646-\u0645\u0648\u0633\u06cc-\u0627\u0644\u06a9\u0627\u0638\u0645', u'\u0627\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631 \u0631\u0633\u0627\u0646\u0647\u200c\u0647\u0627']

a = u', '.join(l)

print a
```

output:

```
شبکه محبان اهل بیت علیهم السلام, آخرین فعالیت ها در هادی نت برگرفته از نام امام نقی علیه السلام, ورود, آخرین آنلاین ها, کاربران فعال, گروه های فعال, محبوبترین برچسب ها, به پاتوق اینترنتی محبان اهل بیت علیهم السلام خوش آمدید, یا حسین(ع)...

می برم یک روز از اصلیتم
آخر از عشقت عراقی می شوم.., #اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم 
#اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم 
#اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم, #اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم
#اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم
#اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم, #اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم 
#اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم 
#اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم, دختران مومن سه ویژگی دارند:
      متکبر،بخیل و ترسو هستند!

 ﺍمیرالمؤمنین ﻋﻠﯽ (علیه السلام) ﻣﯽ ﻓﺮﻣﺎﯾﻨﺪ:

ﺯﻧﺎﻥ ﻭ ﺩﺧﺘﺮﺍﻥ ﻣﻮﻣﻦ ﺑﺎﯾﺪ ﺍﯾﻦ ﺳﻪ ﺻﻔﺖ ﺭﺍ ﮐﻪ ﺑﺮﺍﯼ ﻣﺮﺩﺍﻥ ﺑﺪ ﺍﺳﺖ،ﺩﺍﺷﺘﻪ ﺑﺎﺷﻨﺪ.

ﺍﻭﻝ ﺍﯾﻨﮑﻪ ﻣﺘﮑﺒﺮ ﺑﺎﺷﻨﺪ.

ﺩﯾﮕﺮ ﺍﯾﻨﮑﻪ ﺗﺮﺳﻮ ﺑﺎﺷﻨﺪ.

ﻭ ﺳﻮﻡ ﻫﻢ ﺍﯾﻨﮑﻪ ﺑﺨﯿﻞ ﺑﺎﺷﻨﺪ.


ﺍﻣﺎ ﺍﯾﻨﮑﻪ ﻣﺘﮑﺒﺮ ﺑﺎﺷﻨﺪ ﯾﻌﻨﯽ ﺩﺭ ﻣﻘﺎﺑﻞ ﻧﺎﻣﺤﺮﻡ ﺑﺎ ﻗﺎﻃﻌﯿﺖ ﻭ ﺗﺮﺷﺮﻭﯾﯽ ﺻﺤﺒﺖ ﮐﻨﻨﺪ ﻭ ﺍﺯ ﺣﺮﻑ ﺯﺩﻥ ﺑﺎ ﻋﺸﻮﻩ ﻭ ﺗﺒﺴﻢ ﮐﻪ ﺩﯾﮕﺮﺍﻥ ﺭﺍ ﺗﺤﺮﯾﮏ ﻣﯿﮑﻨﺪ ﺑﭙﺮﻫﯿﺰﻧﺪ.

ﻣﻨﻈﻮﺭ ﺍﺯ ﺗﺮﺱ ﻫﻢ ﺗﺮﺱ ﺍﺯ ﺗﻨﻬﺎ ﺑﻮﺩﻥ ﻭ ﺗﻨﻬﺎ ﻣﺎﻧﺪﻥ ﺑﺎ ﺷﺨﺼﯽ ﺍﺳﺖ ﮐﻪ ﻋﻨﻮﺍﻥ ﻧﺎﻣﺤﺮﻡ ﺩﺍﺭﺩ.

ﺍﻣﺎ ﺍﯾﻨﮑﻪ ﺑﺨﯿﻞ ﺑﺎﺷﺪ ﯾﻌﻨﯽ ﺩﺭ ﺣﻔﻆ ﻣﺎل ﺧﻮﺩ ﻭ ﺷﻮﻫﺮ،ﮐﻤﺎﻝ ﺩﻗﺖ ﻭ ﻭﺳﻮﺍﺱ ﺭﺍ ﺑﻪ ﺧﺮﺝ ﺩﻫﺪ ﻭ ﺍﻣﺎﻧﺖ ﺩﺍﺭ ﺍﻣﻮﺍﻝ ﻫﻤﺴﺮ ﺧﻮﺩ ﺑﺎﺷﺪ.

ﻧﻬﺞ ﺍﻟﺒﻼ‌ﻏﻪ ﻓﯿﺾ ﺍﻻ‌ﺳﻼ‌م ﺣﮑﻤﺖ266،ﺹ1191, #اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم, #اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم, #اللّهـُــمَّ صَـلِّ عَلـی #مُحَــمَّد وَآلِ #مُحَــمَّد وَعَجِّــلْ فـَـَرَجَـهُم 

اللهم عجل لولیک الفرج, , , ........., ان شاءالله قسمت همه عاشقان از جمله شما بشه., ممنون ان شاءالله, ++++++++, عکس و متن فوق العاده س 

خرابه چراغونه امشب ..., , السلام علیک یا سید السادات الاعاظم #احمد-بن-موسی-الکاظم, اخبار رسانه‌ها
```